# Переопределение методов, полиморфизм

Tags: java, полиморфизм

Имеется код:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        A a2 = new C();
        a2.m1();
        a2.m2();
        a2.m3();
    }
}
class A{
    int ivar = 7;
    void m1(){
        System.out.print("A's m1, ");
    }
    void m2(){
        System.out.print("A's m2, ");
    }
    void m3(){
        System.out.print("A's m3, ");
    }
}
class B extends A{
    void m1(){
        System.out.print("B's m1 ");
    }
}
class C extends B{
    void m3(){
        System.out.print("C's m3 "+(ivar+6));
    }
}
```

Программа выводит вот такое сообщение : 
**B's m1 A's m2, C's m3 13**
Правильно ли я понимаю,что такой результат получается в следствии того что во время вызова

```
a2.m1();
```

компилятор следует вверх по иерархии наследования? То есть сначала проверяет наличие этого метода в классе С, если его там нет, то идём вверх, в класс В, там он есть значит вызываем.И так со всеми?

Comment: `class B` содержит все методы и переменные родителя. вы переопределили метод `m1()`, методы `m2()`, `m3()` остаются унаследованными от родителя

Comment: у Вас пример как по учебнику.

Comment: @username Да. это из учебника, это задание.

Comment: @username если m2(), m3() остаются унаследованными от родителя класса B, а значит это методы А. То каким образом сработал метод класса С?

Comment: @username всё, понял. не проснулся ещё наверное) Спасибо

Comment: на момент создания `class B` у Вас создается отдельный класс и выделяется область в памяти под него с методами и переменными родителя. Это не означает что каждый раз когда Вы обращаетесь к `class B` он смотрит в родителя

Comment: @username я понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

совершенно верно. в классе С в итоге есть 3 метода и переменная. никто из них не приватный значит всеми можно пользоваться m1 был переопределен на первой этапе полиморфирования, m3 на втором

Comment: И вам спасибо .